# Any brackets in a link description breaks the link when another is added

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, asking-questions, images

If the alt-text for an image contains the text `\]`, the image breaks whenever you add another image or link through the GUI. This may seem a little bit of an edge-case, but if you want to incorporate LaTeX as the alt-text for a math image on a site other than Math.SE, it can easily happen. Example [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88977/).

Comment: True, but you don't really need all of this in there. It's just the image alternative text, you know

Comment: Why would you put this in the alt text? I can't see us supporting such a strange case that seems very unnecessary.

Comment: @NickCraver I'm currently removing enough to make it reasonable.